# Form not submitted after a second call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to submit a form if a condition is not validated.

```
    <form action="http://www.google.com" method="post" id="support_form">
<p class="accept"><input type="checkbox" id="id_cgu" name="cgu" value="1"> I accept
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>

<script language="javascript">

$("#support_form").submit(function() {
    if($("#id_cgu:checked").length==0) {
        alert("{% trans "Vous must accept terms of services" %}");
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('valid')
        return true;
    }
});

</script>
```

If my form is valid on the first call, my form is well submitted (redirection to another page)

If my form is not valid the first time, and I correct it then, I see the alert box "valid", but my form is not submitted.

Do you have an idea about this problem ?

Comment: remove the `return true` there... ;)

Comment: On what browser/version can you reproduce the issue? I tried on the latest firefox (using a plain "string" instead of your {% %}) and it works just fine. I'm assuming you load your js code on document.ready and you close the input and p tags. It also doesn't hurt if you put a ';' after alert('valid') [if you minimize the code you should]

Comment: I also tried to reproduced this, and the [ **code seems to work** ](http://jsfiddle.net/BaEpw/). Could you provide a link to an example where it doesn't submit after checking the box following an initial unchecked box?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you returned `false`. You should instead use `stopImmediatePropagation();`, like this:

```
$("#support_form").submit(function(ev) {
if($("#id_cgu:checked").length==0) {
    alert("{% trans "Vous must accept terms of services" %}");
    ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
} //rest of code...
```

When you return false, you essentially make that submit button useless until you reload the page.